# Remove the current View Controller from the stack and move to a new View Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

In my app the first time the user accesses a page it downloads the data for that section. The app sends the user to the download page the first time and after everything is downloaded it continues on the content.

I have a very roundabout way of doing it now using Userdefaults. Is there a nice way to dismiss the current view controller and segue to a new one at the same time.

The views are embedded in a navigation controller so ideally, I want to remove the download view controller from the stack as soon as it's finished downloading so if the user hits back, it goes back to the main menu rather than back to the download page.

Comment: Do you want to do this using segues or programmatically?

Comment: Id like to do it either way, just want the end product to be a navigation controller stack with the intro page and the content page.